# How can I access elements in the HTML file via Python?

Tags: python, html

I have an HTML file where my website is built. Next door, I have a Python file where I will write methods. I want when the save button is clicked, it executes a method in the Pythonfile and then writes the values to text area.

When the Start button is pressed, values read by a sensor are to be written into the two text fields (above) and disable this butten, bat enable the other button.

MyHTML-Code.

```
<div class="container">
  <h1 id="h1Title" font="43px">Temperature und humidity</h1>
  <p id="pTemperature " font="25px">Temperature </p>
  <p id="pHumidity" font="25px">humidity</p>
  <p id="OutputTemp" font="25px">--°C</p>
  <p id="OutputHumi" font="25px">--%</p>
  <span class="cbtn" id="e6" font="25px"><button id="buttonStart">Start</button></span>
  <span class="cbtn" id="e7" font="25px"><button id="buttonStop">Stop</button></span>
  <p id="pExplemation1" font="25px">Green temperatures Range: between</p>
  <textarea id="TempGreenMin" font="25px"></textarea>
  <p id="pAnd1" font="25px">and</p>
  <textarea id="TempGreenMax" font="25px"></textarea>
  <p id="pExplemation2" font="25px">Gree humidity range: between</p>
  <textarea id="LumiGreenMin" font="25px"></textarea>
  <p id="pAnd2" font="25px">and</p>
  <textarea id="HumiGreenMax" font="25px"></textarea>
  <span class="cbtn" id="e8" font="25px"><button id="buttonSave">Save</button></span>
</div>
```

Comment: What u have tried so far ?

Comment: @ Nishant Nothing. Nothing. I searched the Internet, but I didn't understand the instructions or explanations, so I didn't try anything. I studied the code in the explanations, but I didn't understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to send a POST request to your API (server) in order to indicate whatever reads the weather to do it's task. Said POST request would then return the information which you can display on the page.

[Creating Web APIs with Python and Flask](https://programminghistorian.org/en/lessons/creating-apis-with-python-and-flask)

Comment: I have briefly flown over it and edited it with Ctrl + f, but it has no example with buttonclick. With me, I will only work with button click events.

Answer (score 0):

You want to have a look at [Flask](http://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/). It is a framework that will allow you to build a website run on python, and run it on your computer so that you can present your readings as an html.

You could also simply have your code to printout the sensor readings to a console.

Comment: I already looked. I make the Tutorial from [Flask](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world)